# Replace NaN of rows using data from another rows

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rows

I have a dataset like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'], 'City': [1, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan], 'Club': [2, 4, 6, np.nan, np.nan], 'Date': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'g']})

Name    City    Club     Date
 A       1        2        x
 B       3        4        y
 C       5        6        z
 A      NaN      NaN       n
 B      NaN      NaN       g
```

How do I use values from "A" and "B" in previous rows to replace NaN in the new rows?

Expected:

```sh
Name    City    Club     Date
 A       1        2        x
 B       3        4        y
 C       5        6        z
 A       1        2        n
 B       3        4        g
```

So far I tired `df['City'].fillna( method ='ffill', inplace = True)`,
but it only allows me to fill missing value one column.

If I use `df['City','Club'].fillna( method ='ffill', inplace = True)` I got `KeyError: ('City', 'Club')`.

Comment: `df[['City', 'Club']] = df.groupby('Name', sort=False)[['City', 'Club']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill')).astype(int)`

Comment: `df[['City', 'Club']]` not `df['City','Club']` when there is more than one column.